# placing and sizing tikz nodes based on page percentages

Tags: tikz-pgf

Tikz newbie here so I'm sure this is very easy but I can't figure it out. Please help!

What I would like to do is place nodes at specific places on the page with specific sizes, all based on the total percentage of the page. For example, say I wish to place a box that takes up 10% of the total width of the page and 20% of the total length and place this box whereby the top left corner of it is 2% to the right and 3% down from the top left corner of the page.

Is there a simple way to do this? I'd give a code snippet but I don't actually have one.

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to TEXSE. Without a code in the form of a MWE, it's really hard to give you a concrete answer. And, please do note that this is not a `just-do-it-for-me` site. As a first step, start with the manual of pgf:)

Answer (score 3):

You need to run this twice. If you want to have access to the text area, use `tikzpagenodes`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
 \fill[blue] (current page.north west)+(0.02\paperwidth,-0.03\paperheight) rectangle
 ++ (0.1\paperwidth,-0.2\paperheight);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

For texts you can use

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
 \draw (current page.north west)+(0.02\paperwidth,-0.03\paperheight) rectangle
 ++ (0.1\paperwidth,-0.2\paperheight) node[midway] {Hello};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]